# How can i give one time Mass discount for admin create order

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

I am created one manual order for a customer, which consists 100 products, how can I give 40% discount for total order value, how can I do that, individual order discount is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to add a ***Shopping Cart Price Rule***?

**Conditions:**

[image: Conditions]

**Actions:**

[image: Actions]

---

**Edit:**

You can alter order amount with this script

> MAGENTO_ROOT/filename.php?id=YOUR_ORDER_ID&discount=DISCOUNT_PERCENT

```
<?php
require_once('./app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$request = Mage::app()->getRequest();

$orderId = (int) $request->getParam('id', 0);
$discount = (int) $request->getParam('discount', 0);

if ($orderId && $discount) {
    // $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

    if ($order) {
        $discountAmmount = $order->getSubtotal() * $discount / 100;
        $grandTotal      = $order->getSubtotal() - $discountAmmount;

        $order->setDiscountAmount($discountAmmount)->setBaseDiscountAmout($discountAmmount);
        $order->setGrandTotal($grandTotal)->setBaseGrandTotal($grandTotal);
        $order->save();
    }
}
```

**Note:** this is **not** complete! You may also adjust tax amount and maybe item base prices. Also this is accessable for everybody, you should add an IP restriction. **So I do not recommend to use it as it is!**

Comment: This one also good, but every custom order count may vary, how can i edit total order value at the order creation.

Comment: Mhhh ... if you create the order from backend you can manually set an individual price.

Comment: Every time individual price assigning takes more times, that's why I am searching time speed up.

Comment: Updated answer to change discount programmatically ... if this is what you're looking for, i can complete this code later ...

Comment: there is no issue about tax, let me check in my localhost.

Comment: Is this complete code?

Comment: Yes, just w/o changing tax amounts. Tested it yesterday and it worked for me. Just would add an IP restriction ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60049/discussion-between-rathinam-and-sv3n).

Comment: I'm there .... answers can be delayed a bit ;)

Comment: okay,    ............

Comment: @sv3n : could you pls tell me the procedure how to run,

Comment: @sv3n :  www.abcd.com/filename.php?id=1234567&discount=10 and code : Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::1);  $orderId = (int) $request->getParam('id', 0);
$discount = (int) $request->getParam('discount', 0);    is my code and run procedure is right?

Comment: Just upload an file with above content and call it from your browser, as you did ...  `www.abcd.com/filename.php?id=1234567&discount=10`

Comment: actually my store id = 1, but code not run...Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::1);

Comment: You dont have to change this line.

Comment: code : http://pasted.co/38b2a708   error : https://snag.gy/jQSh8d.jpg

Comment: http://localhost/xyz/reeditprice.php?id=400000001&discount=10

Comment: @sv3n Is anything else need to follow?

Comment: I used the internal ID .... have update the answer to use increment ID.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60164/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-sv3n).

Comment: @sv3n How can I apply Discount for Total order while creating. The custom order creates by Admin.

Comment: @zus can you please open a new question?

Comment: @sv3n https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/212197/57334