# How can I apply Order Discount. Order Create By admin

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, orders, discount

How can I apply the discount for total order in custom order create for the customer?

**Note : My discount amount may vary for every order**

Is possible?

Comment: you are creating the order programtically?

Comment: No, manual order creates by admin.

Comment: follow this tutorial http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/

Comment: Above link only for fees, not about order discount.. Please correct me if it is.

Comment: https://justpaste.it/1gpd0

Comment: you can use coupon code too for that and also adding fee in -5 will deduct the price from order total

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72752/discussion-between-zus-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: Instead to offer a bounty, it would be better ask a clear question ;)

Comment: @sv3n Is okay my clarity?

Comment: To be honest, no . You want to create an order from backend and want to apply some discount. OK. Have you tried price rules or coupon codes? Please spent some effort before ask. You dont need to be a programmer, but you can try to put it in words to narrow down the solution.

Comment: on what conditions you want to apply discount/s and there are options in admin panel to manage this , that is to set discount rules. Did you tried that ??

Answer (score 0):

Will the same discount amount be applicable for every order created via admin? If your answer is yes then
1. add a checkbox in the form titled something like - `Give discount`
2. In observer `sales_order_place_after` , check the value of this input
3. If set to yes calculate the discount and set it to discount amount

Hope it helps!

Comment: No, my discount may vary from each order.